# does yield break work the same as stop coroutine? unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

the question is pretty obvious. does yield break work the same as stop coroutine () and if it is then what is the difference?

Answer (score 3):

They have the same effect, but they are not the same thing.

`yield break` will end an enumerator, as it signals iteration is complete. A `yield break` statement in an enumerator can be thought of as equivalent to a `goto` to the end of the enumerator function.

A Unity Coroutine uses the enumerator framework, but any function that returns `IEnumerator` can be an iterator, you don't need to use Coruoutines to get this behaviour. It only becomes a Coroutine when you call `StartCoroutine` with an iterator method as the argument.

A Couroutne is simply an iterator that is attached to a monobehabiour that will have `MoveNext` called once per update.

Calling `StopCoroutine` therefore, simply tells the monobehaviour to stop calling `MoveNext` and to dispose of the iterator.

So why are there two ways to do this? Because they have different use-cases.
`yield break` can only be called from within a coroutine (enumerator), and `StopCoroutine` can be called from outside the couroutine.